# How to default to the most recent date in a drop down box in SAS Visual analytics

Tags: sas

In a Visual Analytics report in SAS VIYA 3.5, I have a drop down box to select the date for which to show the data.

**By default, I want to show the current situation, i.e. the last date present in the data.**

In the settings for a drop down box, **there is an "Initially select first item" check box**, but no option to initially select the last, or an option to sort in reverse order.

The solution suggested in different fora is to lookup the data item used in the drop down **in the in data pane, right click it and change its sorting order. However that only works with so called "categorical" variables and SAS VA does not see dates as categorical variables.**

**Does anyone know a workaround?**

*For completeness: a picture in the data pane, date variables are shown with a calendar icon (In this case the date is calculated from a time stamp. That is why there is a calculator in the icon too.) Categorical variables are shown with a tree legged symbol. The context menu for categorical variables has a Custom sort option. That for dates not.*

[image]

Comment: You should be able to sort date in reverse order within the control, then use "Initially Select First Item"

Comment: That is exactly the answer I got from https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Visual-Analytics/How-to-select-the-most-recent-date-in-a-drop-down-box-in-Visual/m-p/836953#M16518 , but it does not work for me. Which version of SAS VIYA are you running? `%put &SYSVLONG4;` I run `V.03.05M0P11112019`.

Comment: Oh, I just got more details on the SAS communies website: It works if you right click the interior of the drop down box, not the dots right of it. GGRRR!!!!

Comment: @StuSztukowski, As Stackoverflow is a knowledge base, not a chat box, this question needs to be answered formaly. As you were the first to come up with the solution, I give you one day to do so and earn the credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort a date in descending order within a drop-down list, right-click in the middle of the drop-down (not the 3 dots) and select Sort --> Date: Descending. Enable the "Initially Select First Item" option on the drop-down and the first date will automatically be selected.

[image]

[image]